# SPRING MVC 3 - NOT displaying image in JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a controller serving images from an external directory (say c:\images\userID\photo.png), and this controller does its job very well. However, the img tag in my JSP file shows the image icon instead of the image returned by this controller.

Here's my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/load/{imageId}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> loadImage(@PathVariable("imageId") Long imageId, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    final org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders headers = new org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders();
    BufferedImage image;
    Photo photo = photoManager.getSinglePhoto(imageId);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);

    try
    {
        if (photo == null)
        {
            File defaultFile = new File("c:/images/default.png");
            image = ImageIO.read(defaultFile);

            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(((DataBufferByte)image.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData(), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }

        File file = new File(photo.getPath());
        image = ImageIO.read(file);
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(((DataBufferByte)image.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData(), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(null, headers, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

I have found reading other answers here, that I need to include messageConverters in my application context, and I did it.

Here's a portion of my application-context.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <util:list>
            <bean id="byteArrayMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The eclipse XML editor complains about MethodHandlerAdapter being deprecated.

JSP:

```
<img src="/mavenspringapp/photo/load/131/" width="128" height="128" alt="laf02.jpg">
```

Why isn't the image getting displayed even when the controller sends the response correctly (201). Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of spring are u using

Comment: it shows the broken image icon even though response is 201

Comment: Could you show the relevant part of your JSP ?

Comment: added relevant part of my JSP file

Comment: any ideas guys? I could really use some help... If more information is needed, I'll add it.

Comment: What do you get if you explicitely type in adress bar of browser : `http://host/mavenspringapp/photo/load/131/`, and could you use Eclipse debugger to control what happens in your controller for that request ?

Comment: I get the same thing... a broken image icon..

Comment: I used the debugger and the method gets executed, it even converts the image to byte[] and it is returned perfectly. I don't know why the JSP is displaying this icon instead of the actual picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the controller method. Apparently loading the image the way I did it, is not correctly done. So I modified my method as shown below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/load/{imageId}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> loadImage(@PathVariable("imageId") Long imageId, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    final org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders headers = new org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders();
    Photo photo = photoManager.getSinglePhoto(imageId);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);

    try
    {
        if (photo == null)
        {
            File defaultFile = new File("c:/images/default.png");
            byte[] content = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(defaultFile);

            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(content, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        File file = new File(photo.getPath());
        byte[] content = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(content, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(null, headers, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

And now it works great! I hope this helps somebody else. Thank you all for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of googling tells me that HTTP 201 means `created`. 
If the image exists, why are you sending a response code telling the client you just created the image?

I don't know for sure how web browsers handle it, but perhaps try changing your response codes to 200, as you aren't really *creating* anything.

Comment: I modified the response code to HttpStatus.OK (200), still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the alternative instead of controller displaying the images you can directly access images your jsp for this you need to put the the mapping information in your spring configuration xml like
 `<mvc:resources mapping="/image/**" location="file:///D:/images/" />` and in your jsp file you can directly can directly call
 `<img src="<spring:url value='/images/logo.png'/>" />` and make sure your have mentioned the spring tag in your jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
```